# Group by with showing full rows in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like below with two columns A, B:

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
SELECT * FROM ( VALUES
  (1,1),
  (1,1),
  (1,2),
  (1,2)
) AS t(a,b);
```

I want the result like below:

```
A B
1 1
1 1
sum B = 2

1 2
1 2
sum B = 4
```

How I can do it in PostgresSQL. Thanks everyone a lot.

Comment: Can you write your result like a _table_? Would '`sum b = 2`' be a text? What's the purpose of the A column ? Are you grouping by B ?

Comment: You probably look for `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` or `GROUP BY ROOLUP` which was added in 9.5

Comment: Why doesn't the table have a unique key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want this

```
SELECT a,b,sum(b)
FROM foo
GROUP BY a,b;

 a | b | sum 
---+---+-----
 1 | 2 |   4
 1 | 1 |   2
```

If you don't want to reduce the row set, you can do this..

```
SELECT a,b,sum(b) OVER (PARTITION BY a,b)
FROM foo;

 a | b | sum 
---+---+-----
 1 | 1 |   2
 1 | 1 |   2
 1 | 2 |   4
 1 | 2 |   4
```

Comment: Can each group add one more row automatically like my question ? It means the results will have 6 rows with each group will have a row named sum. Thanks a lot?

Comment: @ThongNguyen: Columns are named, rows aren't. You could have the option of having a = NULL, b = value, and sum by using `GROUPING SETS`